# Django rest view include one to many related objects in the response

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models as following:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    what_task = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    how_often = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    how_important = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
 )

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.what_task)


class Step(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    what_step = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, )

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.what_step)
```

I have written serializers for them:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = '__all__'
```

And one of my views:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):
    """
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This gives me data like following:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    what_task: "Sample task one",
    how_often: "Daily",
    how_important: "Extremely important",

  }
]
```

However I want to include related `Steps` while retrieving tasks like bellow:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    what_task: "Sample task one",
    how_often: "Daily",
    how_important: "Extremely important",
    steps:[]
  }
]
```

Also, when the user creates a `Task` he can also create `Steps` at the same time for which I can very much expect incoming JSON like above.
How can I achieve that? Do I handle it in serialzers or in view itself?

Comment: Check if this is what you need http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override how the TaskSerializer creates the tasks and steps.

```
class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = '__all__'


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    steps = StepSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        steps_data = validated_data.pop('steps')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for step_data in steps_data:
            Step.objects.create(task=task, **step_data)
        return task
```

You can find details in the documentation: [writable-nested-serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

To create steps when creating a new task, you can do it like this:

```
{
    "what_task": "Sample task one",
    "how_often": "Daily",
    "how_important": "Extremely important",
    "steps": [
        {"what_step": 10},
        {"what_step": 123}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! It is throwing me  `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field steps on serializer TaskSerializer` error. It further says: Original exception text was: 'Task' object has no attribute 'steps'

Comment: It was my mistake, I had forgotten to include related_name='steps' in my model. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I just have one question though: Will it be possible to create steps when I am creating Task? I still do not see any steps related options in my browsable API of Task..

Comment: I added an example of how you can create steps when creating tasks. With the browsable API, you will have to use JSON format when posting data and not the HTML form.